# objc-runtime search_method_list Hangs forever, deadlock?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, objective-c-runtime

macOS/iOS developers, since about two months ago, my app sometimes hangs forever. Then I sample the program i found almost threads, except the main thread is waiting for lock. and the main thread, is executing in the objc-runtime code, like picture below. and the app will not crash, the ,methods will not return :(

[image: Main Thread]

[image: other thread that is executing objc-code, are waiting for lock]

then, i look into the objc-runtime source code[objc-runtime](https://github.com/RetVal/objc-runtime) and compile a debug versin, link to my program.it re-produce the issue. in the function `IMP lookUpImpOrForward(Class cls, SEL sel, id inst, 
                       bool initialize, bool cache, bool resolver)` , main thread did hold the **runtimeLock** and other threads are waiting. but i don't know what might cause the issue, what is the root cause ? any guess ? thanks you all!

Comment: Is there any method swizzling or other runtime editing going on in your application?

Comment: @bbum nope, but we found that some thread/queue have user-interactive qos, maybe that's the reason?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest filing a radar with a simple, reproducible example to apple, they're going to have much more context than any of us here on stack overflow.

If I had to guess, it's some really strange interaction between the class replacement done by KVC, and one of the runtime locks.